# Cannot delete SO Line by non admin user (odoo v11)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I have created Sale Order with some line items.

1. Create many SO with at lest 3 lines with non-admin user (But manager level user)
2. Next day, tried to delete first line of the SO with non-admin user
3. Once press Save, it gives error.

> ```
> User #7 deleted sale.order.line records with IDs: [367]
> ERROR db_name odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 947, in __get__
>     value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 960, in get
>     value = self._data[field][record.id][key]
> KeyError: (<odoo.sql_db.Cursor object at 0x7f44b8cc20b8>, 7)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 646, in _handle_exception
>     return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 307, in _handle_exception
>     raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
>     raise value
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
>     result = self._call_function(**self.params)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 339, in _call_function
>     return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
>     return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 332, in checked_call
>     result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 927, in __call__
>     return self.method(*args, **kw)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 512, in response_wrap
>     response = f(*args, **kw)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 930, in call_kw
>     return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-ackages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py" line 922, in _call_kw
>     return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
>     return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
>     result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/sale/sale.py", line 1285, in write
>     result = super(SaleOrder, self).write(vals)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 277, in write
>     result = super(MailThread, self).write(values)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3008, in write
>     self._write(old_vals)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3223, in _write
>     self.recompute()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4801, in recompute
>     vals = {n: rec[n] for n in ns}
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4801, in <dictcomp>
>     vals = {n: rec[n] for n in ns}
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4659, in __getitem__
>     return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 954, in __get__
>     value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 960, in get
>     value = self._data[field][record.id][key]
> KeyError: (<odoo.sql_db.Cursor object at 0x7f44b8cc20b8>, 7)
> ```

Please suggest the solution as the other non admin user should be able to edit the order line items. They can not ask all the time the Administrator to do so.

Comment: Initially check rights weather this user is rights to delete. If yes then try to delete by cancelling SO.

Comment: Do you have customization installed? If so, there probably was made a mistake. I don't know of such errors in Odoo core codebase. It is obviously no access problem.

Comment: Yes there are some custom module installed but I checked everything correct the user created has also right to create, edit, delete. The problem is only for to delete the first line item. Does odoo v11 have any sequence relation ?

I found an issue raised in GitHub

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/23354

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with the following code.

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    if 'unlink_so_line' in self.env.context:
        return super(sale_order_line, self).unlink()
    else:
        self.env.context = dict(self.env.context)
        self.env.context.update({'unlink_so_line': True})
        return super(sale_order_line, self).sudo().unlink()
```

When you only unlink with sudo(), the unlink goes into a look, and you will get an error message that the maximum recursion depth is exceeded.